# Как сделать слово в tkinter.Text кнопкой Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Делаю приложение для проверки орфографии и хочу, чтобы при нахождении слова с ошибкой на него можно было нажать и сверху появился вариант исправления. Как можно сделать так, чтобы на слово можно было нажать?

Comment: Попробуйте каждое слово кинуть в Label или button =)

Comment: Можно к тексту привязать теги, для которых можно добавить оформление (например, подчеркивание) и реакцию на события (например, отображение контекстного меню при клике), см https://younglinux.info/tkinter/text

Comment: @insolor спасибо, но не особо помогло. Нашел отдаленно похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget, но тоже не то. Сейчас в голову пришла идея взять координаты каждого слова в тексте с помощью словаря `{'слово1': (1.1, 1.5)}` (координаты в формате `(колонка_начала.столбец_начала, колонка_конец.столбец_конец)` и каким-то образом найти координаты курсора. Если координаты слова совпадают с мышкой и происходит нажатие, то со словом что-то будет происходит

Comment: Понял. К тегам можно применить `bind`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951158/how-to-make-text-clickable-in-tkinter-python-on-ubuntu